# Does ReactiveUI have an alternative solution, similar to an Event Aggregator for sending messages between modules?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui, avaloniaui

I have 2 modules and both don't know of each other's existence. The only thing they have in common is that they branched out from the same MainViewModel. One of them needs to inform the other about an update happening in the UI or about data being updated and I need to find a way to do it.

A great solution I found is an Event Aggregator, but I'm not sure if I should use it. Does ReactiveUI have an alternative approach of handling something like that?

Comment: Is [ReactiveUI's Message Bus](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/message-bus/) what you are looking for?

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know an Event Aggregator had 2 names. Thank you!